# Can't boot into linux on USB

Tags: boot, bootable

I recently got a new laptop (Acer Aspire A515-48M) and I can't get it to boot linux.
I burnt Ubuntu 22.04 on a USB pen drive with rufus (GPT partition scheme, FAT32 FS). In the BIOS, I disabled fastboot. Then I selected Ubuntu from the F12 boot menu, after which the Ubuntu GRUB page shows up (with option to install Ubuntu, safe graphics, OEM install...). After selecting the first option (install), the screen goes black for a second before the machine reboots and throws me back into GRUB.

Troubleshooting steps I have taken so far:

- use mbr scheme in rufus (I don't think this should work since this laptop does not seem to support legacy boot, in BIOS, the boot mode is set to UEFI and I cannot change it)
- in rufus, write the image in dd mode
- use a different distro (rocky 9.3)
- select any of the other options in GRUB (safe graphics and OEM install)
- disable secure boot
- add a line in grub.cfg: 'set debug=linux,video'. This gives no errors at all, the last line shows 'loader/efi/linux.c:167: kernel_addr: 0x1000000 handover_offset: 0x190 params: 0x7ffff000' before rebooting

All of these tests gave the same result, I never get any further than GRUB. What else can I try to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the usb is booting fine, but the black screen is a possible sign of a video driver issue.  Try booting in safe graphics mode, or add nomodeset to the kernel command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it sadly does not make a difference though. The machine still reboots at the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an outdated BIOS. Installed the most recent version that's available on Acer's website and now I can boot from a USB.